# Some website doesnt open in chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, 22.04, browser, opera

I'm using ubuntu 22.04. Since last week my **chrome** doesn't open particular websites Like Spatial chat and Duolingo(I have the same problem with the **opera** browser) But I can open these websites in firefox, I tried these ways to solve my problem but nothing change:

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Kz9.png)

[details picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGVWi.png)

**1.** clear cache and cookies in chrome.

**2.** resolve all extensions in chrome.

**3.** try to open these websites in the Incognito tab but it doesn't open these sites too.

**4.**  install chrome again.

thank you for your help!

Comment: Any error message? And is your system fully updated?

Comment: sorry I attach the picture now

Comment: click on the details button and write the output to your answer

Comment: @Amirreza I add this picture to the question: detail picture

Comment: I guess it's due to a DNS issue, change your DNS in the settings to 4.2.2.4, or change it to "use system's setting"

Comment: @Amirreza DNS setting by default is automatic. I try these websites with another computer and there is the same problem!!! can it be related to my Internet connection?!

Comment: it definitely is about the network I'm just wondering why Firefox can open them, Opera, Safari, Chrome and Edge all have the same browser engine but Firefox has a different one, ping the URL in your terminal and see whether you can connect to duolingo, run `ping https://duolingo.com`, run `ping 8.8.8.8`, run `ping 4.2.2.4` and just to check the DNS run `ping https://mozilla.org` and write the output of all of the commands to your question.

Comment: @Amirreza I run ping, It seems that there is no problem! my question is if it depends on the internet connection why I can't open these sites with VPN?!

Comment: it's probably the internet connection as you mentioned, probably due to the heavy internet blockade. I suggested some ways to bypass the blockade in the chat (big bro may be watching)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139669/discussion-between-amirreza-and-negin).